# IE10 tbody tag get margin from the table tag in RTL

Tags: html-table, background-color, internet-explorer-10, right-to-left

I have a strange problem with IE10 in RTL, for some reason the “tbody” tag gets some margin from the “table” tag. This problem causes the “td” tag background color to exceed its frame and be over the table border.

The only solution that I found is to add a “direction:ltr” to the table but this solution is not good for me.

[image: Example]

Comment: I also found that if i change the table width from 100% to 99% it fixing the problem but this solution is also not good for me.

Comment: The problem appear also in some IE9 browsers but not in every IE9.

Comment: Just a few observations. 1) table layout! 2) there's a stylesheet included conditionally for _all_ IE although the comments indicate it should only be there for IE<9. 3) there are embedded stylesheets and scripts inside the table, I've seen that cause issues.

Comment: I know all the things that you sayy but nothing will not fix the problem.

Comment: You could try adding an explicit `tbody` to the markup and then `tbody { margin: 0 }` to see if that fixes it?

Comment: try it, It dose not fix it. I think it is a bug in the IE engine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I already try it and its not workking. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Adding "border-collapse:collapse;" to the table fix it.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp